# Access Database get last entry

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make a fairly simple time clock program in VB Net and I will be using an Access Database. So far I have an Employee Table and a ClockEntry Table. What I want to do is access the very last entry of the ClockEntry Table to determine if the employee is clocked in or out. The ClockEntry tabel looks like this:

```
EntryID
EmployeeID
ClockType - IN or OUT
DateTime - Date and time in 4/12/2018 7:00:00 AM format
```

The problem starts with the fact that an employee can forget to clock in or out so I will have an Admin that can do that later for them. But that will make the data out of order date and time wise. That is where I am running into trouble. I need to sort the data by the DateTime field and THEN grab the last entry. When I add the sort by on the DateTime, it gets the LAST and THEN sorts that. It does not sort the list first. Is it possible to get everything in one search/query or do I need to have a separate query?

This is one of the ones I tried:

```
SELECT ClockEntries.ClockType, Last(ClockEntries.DateTime) AS LastOfDateTime
FROM ClockEntries
GROUP BY ClockEntries.ClockType, ClockEntries.EmployeeID
HAVING (((ClockEntries.EmployeeID)=1))
ORDER BY Last(ClockEntries.DateTime);
```

I get the last IN and OUT (two entries) sorted by the DateTime field but it is the last entries BEFORE being sorted by DateTime and not the last ones sorted by all date entries (hopefully that makes sense).

Basically I want the very last entry (one entry) for an employee and what type it was (IN or OUT)...but I want the last of the sorted data (most recent date).

Comment: I made a query that basically sorts the ClockEntries table by DateTime and that is all it does. The I made a new query using that query and it works but it gives me two entries again (the last IN and the last OUT). I am not sure how to stop that. I will post the query in another comment.

Comment: SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.EmployeePassword, Employees.EmployeeName, Employees.EmployeeStatus, Last(Query1.DateTime) AS LastOfDateTime
FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Query1 ON Employees.EmployeeID = Query1.EmployeeID
WHERE (((Query1.ClockType)='IN' Or (Query1.ClockType)='OUT'))
GROUP BY Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.EmployeePassword, Employees.EmployeeName, Employees.EmployeeStatus;